# How to correctly type React useState hook with enum in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings

How to type my useState hook correctly?

I have this `enum` type:

```
export enum Status {
  PENDING = 'pending',
  SUCCESS = 'success',
  ERROR = 'error',
}
```

And the `useState` hook: `const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState<// What to add here>(ApiStatus.PENDING);`

So that the value of the useState hook can only be one of the `Status` values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the type as `Status`.

```
const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState<Status>(Status.PENDING)

// valid
setIsValid(Status.PENDING)
setIsValid(Status.SUCCESS)
setIsValid(Status.ERROR)
```

If you also want to allow passing the string values, wrap `Status` into a [*template literal type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

```
const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState<`${Status}`>(Status.PENDING)

// valid
setIsValid(Status.PENDING)
setIsValid(Status.SUCCESS)
setIsValid(Status.ERROR)
setIsValid("pending")
setIsValid("success")
setIsValid("error")
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgtgDg9gTgFwAQG8kFcDOBTAyggQwWyQF8kAzOGCJAIjmwIGME7RRsAPWRJbAHbpa+IllSgkSAAoBRAHIARAJLyA4kgC8SAORRBAEzACA5joA0kpLgCqAYTuzcuLbszpmzbJkwWrsgCUAgHkA1x1sOGo4PxBSDhBmGAFMZABtMEwANQIAGzADcyQcBGVsvIKAXVcsPEJiAB4AAwASFFEELFImgD4ACg6sADo5JVU1AEoEkrKc-IMB+uHAkICpkBny+b66SOi6CaA)

Answer (score 0):

If you tweek your enum keys to be the same as values, you can do this with `keyof` and `typeof` as follows:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export enum Status {
  pending = "pending",
  success = "success",
  error = "error"
}

export default function App() {
  const [st, setSt] = useState<keyof typeof Status>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setSt(Status.error);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-elbakyan-5gfyxp?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: `Argument of type 'Status.ERROR' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<"PENDING" | "SUCCESS" | "ERROR" | undefined>'`?

Comment: Hm, acknowledged. I did not see that the values were different than keys thanks